# Pass \ in command line arguments of C++

Tags: c++, regex, command-line-arguments

I am working on a C++ program where one of the command line arguments needs to be a passed a regex. For example: `abc.exe --option ab\[0\]`

When I access the option value from inside the program, it becomes `ab\\[0\\]` which becomes a different regex.
Inside the program when I try to replace `\\[` with `\[` using `boost::replace_all`, the result is `[` which also is not the intended output for me.

So, any suggestions on how to pass and retain `\[` this while passing it through command line arguments

Comment: Show the code for your boost replace, are you escaping your backslashes? You will likely need to be replacing `\\\\[` with `\\[`  ...

Comment: Try quotes? It's hard to say without the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can quote the parameter:

```
abc.exe --option "ab\[0\]"
```

Or use the shell escape sequence:

```
abc.exe --option ab\\[0\\]
```

Did you try these?

Comment: If I put ```"ab\[0\]"```. The value inside the program is same i.e. ```"ab\\[0\\]"```
If passed as ```ab\\[0\\]```. It becomes ```"ab\\\\[0\\\\]"```

Comment: How are you displaying this parameter? It looks like the formatter is inserting to escapes so you can tell that \\[ in the string means the two characters: \[. Display the raw characters. It looks like you are getting what you want.

Comment: Are you displaying the string via printf("%s\n", optString); or using some debugger? printf will not add escape sequences, so I would trust what it shows.

Comment: I am using visual studio. I saw that the ASCII code is still decimal 92, which means it is still just a single \ internally. So I guess it is passing the intended stuffs but only displaying differently

Comment: Yes, sounds like you had it correct right from the start. Visual studio is adding the escapes when it displays, but they are not stored in the string. It's just there for visual representation.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with how visual studio displays the symbol. When I looked on the ASCII code of the symbol, it was alright. Thanks @ScottK for helping me to debug this through your comments